# SQL SERVER 2017 - How do I query to retrieve a group of data only if all of the data inside that group are marked as completed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some observation tables like below. The observation data might be in individual form or grouped form which is determined by the observation category table.

```
cat table (which holds category data)
id   | title    |    is_groupable
-------------------------------------------
1    | Cat 1    |    1
2    | Cat 2    |    1
3    | Cat 3    |    0
4    | Cat 4    |    0
5    | Cat 5    |    1

obs table (Holds observation data, groupable data are indicated by is_groupable of cat table, and the data is grouped in respect to index of obs table. and is_completed field indicates if some action has been taken on that or not)
id   | cat_id   |  index  | is_completed |  created_at
------------------------------------------------------
1    | 3        | 100     | 0            | 2017-12-01

2    | 4        | 400     | 1            | 2017-12-02
// complete action taken group indicated by 1 in is_completed field
3    | 1        | 200     | 1            | 2017-12-1
4    | 1        | 200     | 1            | 2017-12-1
// not complete action taken group
5    | 2        | 300     | 0            | 2017-12-1
6    | 2        | 300     | 1            | 2017-12-1
7    | 2        | 300     | 0            | 2017-12-1
// complete action taken group
8    | 5        | 400     | 1            | 2017-12-1
9    | 5        | 400     | 1            | 2017-12-1
10   | 5        | 400     | 1            | 2017-12-1
```

For the sake of easeness in understanding i have separated the set of data as completed or not using the comment above in obs table.

Now what I want to achieve is retrieve the set of data in a group format from obs table. In the above case the set of groups are

```
{3,4} 
{5,6,7}
{8,9,10}
```

i want to get set {3,4} and {8,9,10} in my result since every data in the group are flagged as is_completed: 1
I don't need {5,6,7} set of data because it has only 6 is flagged as completed, 5 and 7 are not taken action and hence not completed.

What I have done till now is
(Lets ignore the individual case, because It is very easy and already completed and for the group case as well, Im able to retrieve the group data, if ignoring the action taken case, ie I able to group them and retrieve the sets irrespective of taken action or not.)

```
(SELECT
null AS id,
cat.is_groupable AS is_grouped,
cat.title,
cat.id AS category_id,
o.index,
o.date,
null AS created_at,
null AS is_action_taken,

(
  --  individual observation
  SELECT
    oi.id AS "observation.id",
    oi.category_id AS "observation.category_id",
    oi.index AS "observation.index",
    oi.created_at AS "observation.created_at",

    -- action taken flag according to is_completed
    CAST(
      CASE 
          WHEN ((oi.is_completed) > 0) THEN 1
          ELSE 0
      END AS BIT
    ) AS "observation.is_action_taken",

    -- we might do some sort of comparison here
    CAST(
    (
       CASE
      --
      -- Check if total count == completed count
      WHEN (
          SELECT COUNT(obs.id)
           FROM obs
            WHERE obs.category_id = cat.id AND obs.index = o.index
      ) = (
          SELECT COUNT(obs.id)
          FROM obs
          WHERE obs.category_id = cat.id AND oi.index = o.index 
          AND oi.is_action_taken = 1
        ) then 1
      else 0
    end
  ) as bit
) as all_completed_in_group

  FROM observations oi  
  WHERE oi.category_id = cat.id
    AND oi.index = o.index
  FOR JSON PATH
) AS observations
FROM obs o
INNER JOIN cat ON cat.id = o.category_id
WHERE cat.is_groupable = 1
GROUP BY cat.id, cat.name, o.index, cat.is_groupable, o.created_at
)
```

Let's not get over on if this query executes successfully or not. I just want idea, if there is any better approach than this one, or if this approach is correct or not.

Comment: What is "group format"?

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand what you mean, but by grouping of data, i mean to retrieve the grouped data in json format, because I can't think of any other format where i can retrieve multiple row of data grouped in single row. And yes, I am working on API so, needed to be in JSON format, as indicated by FOR JSON PATH. 
If you can suggest any better, im open to it.

Comment: Im creating a sql fiddle for this question, just wait for that to complete please.

Comment: @Yegya  did you find anything useful? Please accept one solution

Comment: @Simone still figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you need. To check the group completeness I just used `AND NOT EXISTS` for the group that has an `is_completed = '0'`.  The inner join is used to get the corresponding obs id's. The algorithm is put in a CTE (common table expression).  Then I use STUFF on the CTE to get the output.

```
DECLARE @cat TABLE (id int, title varchar(100), is_groupable bit)
INSERT INTO @cat VALUES
 (1, 'Cat 1', 1), (2, 'Cat 2', 1), (3, 'Cat 3', 0), (4, 'Cat 4', 0), (5, 'Cat 5', 1)

DECLARE @obs TABLE (id int, cat_id int, [index] int, is_completed bit, created_at date)
INSERT INTO @obs VALUES
 (1, 3, 100, 0, '2017-12-01'), (2, 4, 400, 1, '2017-12-02')
-- complete action taken group indicated by 1 in is_completed field
,(3, 1, 200, 1, '2017-12-01'), (4, 1, 200, 1, '2017-12-01')
-- not complete action taken group
,(5, 2, 300, 0, '2017-12-01'), (6, 2, 300, 1, '2017-12-01'), (7, 2, 300, 0, '2017-12-01')
-- complete action taken group
,(8, 5, 400, 1, '2017-12-01'), (9, 5, 400, 1, '2017-12-01'), (10, 5, 400, 1, '2017-12-01')
;
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT C.id [cat_id]
      ,O2.id [obs_id]
  FROM @cat C INNER JOIN @obs O2 ON C.id = O2.cat_id
 WHERE C.is_groupable = 1 --is a group
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM @obs O
                    WHERE O.cat_id = C.id
                      AND O.is_completed = '0'
                      --everything in the group is_completed
                  )
)
--Stuff will put everything on one row
SELECT DISTINCT 
          '{' 
        + STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(C2.obs_id as varchar)
                   FROM cte C2
                  WHERE C2.cat_id = C1.cat_id
                 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
        + '}' AS returnvals
  FROM cte C1
```

Produces output:

```
returnvals
{3,4}
{8,9,10}
```

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle for this. I'm not able to run the query you provided.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d394a/3

Comment: Here you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25a755/2    ... the above could be run as-is in sql server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this approach, the trick is using the sum of completed to be checked against the total present for the group.

```
;WITH aux AS (
SELECT o.cat_id, COUNT(o.id) Tot, SUM(CONVERT(int, o.is_completed)) Compl, MIN(CONVERT(int, c.is_groupable)) is_groupable
FROM obs o INNER JOIN cat c ON o.cat_id = c.id
GROUP BY o.cat_id
)
, res AS ( 
SELECT o.*, a.is_groupable
FROM obs o INNER JOIN aux a ON o.cat_id = a.cat_id
WHERE (a.Tot = a.Compl AND a.is_groupable = 1) OR a.Tot = 1
)
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10), id) id, CONVERT(nvarchar(10), cat_id) cat_id
INTO #res
FROM res
SELECT * FROM #res
SELECT m.cat_id, LEFT(m.results,Len(m.results)-1) AS DataGroup
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT r2.cat_id, 
  (
    SELECT r1.id + ',' AS [text()]
    FROM #res r1
    WHERE r1.cat_id = r2.cat_id
    ORDER BY r1.cat_id
    FOR XML PATH ('')
  ) results
  FROM #res r2
) m
ORDER BY DataGroup
DROP TABLE #res
```

The conversion is due to bit datatype